# Nodejs promise pending

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, redis, promise

I'm trying to make an constructor for multiple Redis connections, so i've started to try something.
I'm only getting back from has Promise {  }, but if I do an console.log before the return I'm getting the real Value.

EDIT: Tried without async/await still don't work.

app.js

```
const rBredis = require("./redis");
const redis = new rBredis();
console.log(redis.has("kek"));
```

redis.js

```
const Redis = require("ioredis");
class BasicRedis {
    constructor() {
        // TODO
    };
    redis = new Redis();
    async has(id) {
        return await this.redis.exists(id)
            .then( exists => {
                // console.log(exists); works 0
                return exists; // works not Promise { <pending> }
            });
    };
}
module.exports = BasicRedis;
```

Comment: You `has()` method doesn't return anything.

Comment: you should do  ```return await this.redis.exists(id)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your question completely but I see a problem here. 
You need to brush up your knowledge of Promises and Async await. You either use async 
await or Promises (.then) syntax to make it work properly.

redis.js

```
class BasicRedis {
    constructor() {
        // TODO
    };
    redis = new Redis();
// You can either do it like this
    has(id) {
         return new Promise((res, rej) => {
           this.redis.exists(id)
             .then( exists => {
                res(exists)
             }).catch(err => {
                rej(err.message)
              });
         })
    };

// Or like this 
     has(id) {
         return this.redis.exists(id)
    };
}
```

In both cases, you can await/.then result in your app.js

```
// app.js
const rBredis = require("./redis");
const redis = new rBredis();
redis.has("kek").then(res => console.log(res))
```

EDIT - 1

If this is something that'd take time even 1 millisecond there's no way you're going to get the value right away. You need to use either async-await or promises. Or use a callback like this

redis.js

```
class BasicRedis {
    constructor() {
        // TODO
    };
    redis = new Redis();

      has(id, callback) {
           this.redis.exists(id)
             .then( exists => {
                callback(exists)
             }).catch(err => {
                callback(err.message)
              });
    };

}
```

app.js

```
const rBredis = require("./redis");
const redis = new rBredis();
redis.has("kek", (res) => console.log(res))
```

Here's reference to [Promises MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [Async Await MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but I've wanted to return only a value and not a promise how can I do that I don't get it.

Comment: @PhilippKlos Hey Phillip, You can check out the edit above. Hope it helps :)
P.S 
Indentation sucks on Stackoverflow 